# How to make IntelliJ Idea display only compiler generated warnings and supress intelligent inspections?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, code-inspection

I am working on IntelliJ Idea 14. Is there a way out for the above?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html. You can suppress per class [Alt + Enter ] but it appears you want to turn it off entirely ?

Comment: offtopic: We use intelliJ for that feature.  Why would you want to turn it off?

Comment: @Jayan We are a bunch of people working on a project with some using eclipse and some intellij. If only compiler generated warnings are reported, they would be consistent across the two editors. Also, intellij shows lot of warnings that we do not want. It becomes irritating. If we supress them, eclipse shows warnings for supression as they are not standard warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Under "Inspections" in the Settings configuration, you can change your inspections profile to exclude the ones you don't want. Also, at the bottom right of the application window you can click on the "little guy in the hat" and turn down the inspections on a file-by-file basis.

Answer (score 0):

Suppressing inspection in general may not be good idea.  You could create multiple [custom profiles](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/customizing-profiles.html#d1529343e18596) and keep it as part of project.  Create a new one called "minimum", which will have inspection that is meaningful to full team. Set that as default for project

Create another which will have much bigger set and run occasionally else where.